# How to zoom in storyboard (Xcode 6)

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

Since yesterday, the new Xcode6 has been released. Is it possible to zoom in the storyboard view?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's possible to zoom out on storyboard, as always.

Edit: Right-click (or ctrl-click) on an empty area of your storyboard to show a contextual menu.

Comment: ehh.. how? I do not have any zoom buttons anymore

Comment: Right-click or ctrl-click on an empty area of your storyboard.

Comment: I only get Interface Builder help, no other options.

Comment: @simpleBob, you have to first click on the project window to make it the key window and give it focus, **then** right-click/control-click in an empty area of the storyboard.

Comment: Thank yoy @DuncanC, It seems that if the window is not focused, the contextual menu is different

Comment: Was this feature removed?  I don't think I've ever seen this in a contextual menu.

Comment: @Ssswift as of Xcode 9 beta 2, the contextual menu is still available.

Comment: It seems to work only for iOS projects. For macOS, there is no zoom menu.

Answer (score 18):

You can zoom in and out by pinching on your trackpad.

You can also use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> to zoom in and out.

Comment: are you doing **⌘⌥[** by accident?

Comment: No, but I have english/german/spanish setting which may mess things up a bit

Comment: This shortcuts actually are set in Xcode/preferences. They just do not work. (to get `{` I have to hit `⌥ + another key`) I am using spanish K/B layout

Comment: just for reference, I am using double click, which actually works

Comment: This only works with Storyboard. Interface builder apparently has no zooming capabilities. Shocking, I know.

Comment: What happened to the zoom controls that were drawn on-screen when you were editing a storyboard? It's very disorienting that they went away. Apple seems to take perverse pleasure in making capricious changes to the UI of their development tools.

Comment: @simpleBob clicking works, but it only toggles between two zoom modes. The keys allow you greater control which is what I assume they're after.

Comment: @capitallt but unfortunately the keys do not work for me, I only can use the double clicking and for greater control I use the context menu

Comment: Also, I cannot change the keys, because I would have to solve a lot of key conflicts I cannot/do not want to solve first.

Comment: I understand simpleBob. I actually am unable to use the keys as well. I'm going to look to see if there is a system configuration that prevents the Xcode hot key from working properly.

Comment: How to zoom past 100%?

Answer (score 4):

Zooming was a bit kludgey in Xcode 6 (pinch-zoom worked best for me), but it looks like zooming has changed for the better in Xcode 7.

In Xcode 7, if you want to zoom your storyboard you can simply use <kbd>**⌘**</kbd>+<kbd>**+**</kbd> to zoom in, and <kbd>**⌘**</kbd>+<kbd>**-**</kbd> to zoom out.

BTW, this is the same key combination Apple uses to zoom in/out in Safari and other apps.

Comment: How to zoom past 100%?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the sloppiest keyboard shortcuts, implemented by Apple. To get `}` you must hit shift, but hitting shift is a system-wide command to slow animations. I really recommend changing the shortcut in preferences.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, the zoom feature doesn't seem to exist for MacOS storyboards :( See discussion [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72495)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, in Xcode 6, the best way to zoom in/out in xib is using the new `Preview` feature in assistant editor, **you can just use touch pad to do normal pinch in/out to do zoom**.

More info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/chapters/PreviewingLayouts.html